# Advantages of stacking LSTMs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I'm wondering in what situations it is advantageous to stack LSTMs?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163304/advantages-of-using-multiple-lstm-s-in-deep-network might be helpful to get an idea??

Answer (score 9):

From [What are the advantages of stacking multiple LSTMs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/163304/12359) (I'll only update the answer there):

> From {1}:
>
> > While it is not theoretically clear what is the additional power gained by the deeper architecture, it was observed empirically that
> >     deep RNNs work better than shallower ones on some tasks. In
> >     particular, Sutskever et al (2014) report that a 4-layers deep
> >     architecture was crucial in achieving good machine-translation
> >     performance in an encoder-decoder framework. Irsoy and Cardie (2014)
> >     also report improved results from moving from a one-layer BI-RNN to an
> >     architecture with several layers. Many other works report result using
> >     layered RNN architectures, but do not explicitly compare to 1-layer
> >     RNNs.
>
> ---
>
> References:
>
> - {1} Goldberg, Yoav. "A Primer on Neural Network Models for Natural Language Processing." J. Artif. Intell. Res.(JAIR) 57 (2016): 345-420.
>     https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3704132192758179278&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5
>     ; http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~yogo/nnlp.pdf

Answer (score 6):

One situation in which it's advantageous to stack LSTMs is when we want to learn hierarchical representation of our time-series data. In stacked LSTMs, each LSTM layer outputs a sequence of vectors which will be used as an input to a subsequent LSTM layer. This hierarchy of hidden layers enables more complex representation of our time-series data, capturing information at different scales.

For example, stacked LSTMs can be used to improve accuracy in time-series classification, such as activity prediction, in which heart-rate, step-count, GPS and other signals can be used to predict activity such as walking, running, biking, climbing stairs or resting. For an example of time-series classification with stacked LSTMs using EEG data have a look at the following [ipython notebook](https://github.com/vsmolyakov/experiments_with_python/blob/master/chp01/keras_lstm_seqclass.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

In sequence to sequence model:
The encoder network’s job is to read the input sequence to our Seq2Seq model and generate a fixed-dimensional context vector C for the sequence. To do so, the encoder will use a recurrent neural network cell – usually an LSTM – to read the input tokens one at a time. The final hidden state of the cell will then become C. However, because it’s so difficult to compress an arbitrary-length sequence in to a single fixed-size vector (especially for difficult tasks like translation), the encoder will usually consist of **stacked LSTMs**: a series of LSTM "layers" where each layer’s outputs are the input sequence to the next layer. The final layer’s LSTM hidden state will be used as Context vector.